# Ler arquivo txt e fazer validações em javascript

Tags: php, javascript

Tenho um arquivo em txt que contem mais de mil linhas, cada linha existe uma númeração que precisa ser validada por um script em javascript que tenho pronto.

Gostaria que algum script em php ou javascript mesmo lesse o arquivo em txt, pegasse linha por linha e fosse validando com o outro script de validação que tenho, e quando validasse, caso a linha seja reprovado na validação, que a mesma seja excluida ou pelo menos marcada com algum caractere especial, mas prefiro que seja removida mesmo.

**Obs:** Tenho servidores Linux que aguentariam o processamento, caso a solução exija muito da maquina.

**Verificação simples que seria utilizada:**

```
var numero = "55555555555"; // Aqui no caso seria puxado o arquivo em txt
if(numero.match(/55555555555/))
{ document.write("OK"); } else{
document.write("Nao Passou");}
```

Existe alguma forma de fazer isso?

Comment: Esse JavaScript estará rodando no navegador ou no Node?

Comment: No navegador ...

Comment: Que tipo de validação é essa? Tem como colocá-la junto a pergunta?

Comment: São validações simples, mas várias, mas um exemplo seria assim:

<script>
var numero = "55555555555"; // Aqui no caso seria puxado o arquivo em txt 
if(numero.match(/55555555555/)){
 document.write("OK");
}
 else{
  document.write("Nao Passou");
 }
</script>

Comment: Coloque na pergunta, por favor. Se são validações simples, recomendo que as implemente em PHP e faça tudo por essa linguagem. Utilize o JS somente se a implementação dessa validação em PHP for inviável.

Comment: Mas não existe alguma forma de fazer do jeito que expliquei?

Comment: Em PHP, sim. É bem fácil, mas preciso que você esclareça na pergunta que tipo de validações são essas.

Comment: Poderia me dar um exemplo de como fazer isso no PHP se eu fosse utilizar apenas uma verificação simples caso em alguma linha do arquivo txt fosse encontrado uma sequencia númerica, exemplo 55555555555? Pq o resto eu conseguiria mudar tudo pra php, só precisaria de um exemplo.

Comment: Vc quer criar o novo arquivo txt na máquina ou no servidor?

Comment: O que for mais viavel, pois o resultado disso seria apenas pra mim, não iria colocar pra usuarios rodarem via navegador, apenas eu mesmo rodaria isso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como comentei, com JavaScript rodando no navegador não será possível - de forma simples, pois o JavaScript não possui acesso aos arquivos. Você comentou que são validações simples, estão será mais viável implementá-las em PHP e executar tudo com essa linguagem.

Para abrir e ler o conteúdo de um arquivo, você pode utilizar a função [`file`](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.file.php):

```
<?php

$file = file("arquivo.txt");

if ($file !== false)
{
    foreach($file as $index => $line)
    {
        // Validação da linha...
    }
}
```

Com base nos seus comentários, a validação citada seria se o valor da linha casa com o padrão `/55555555555/`, definido por uma expressão regular. Considerando que quando o conteúdo da linha não casar com esse padrão a linha deverá ser excluída, pode-se fazer:

```
<?php

$file = file("arquivo.txt");

if ($file !== false)
{
    foreach($file as $index => $line)
    {
        if (!preg_match("/55555555555/", trim($line), $matches))
        {
            unset($file[$index]);
        }
    }
}
```

Assim, o *array* `$file`, após terminar o laço de repetição, possuirá apenas os valores que passaram pela validação. Para escrever novamente no arquivo, basta utilizar a função [`file_put_contents`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.file-put-contents.php) em conjunto com a [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.implode.php):

```
file_put_contents("arquivo.txt", implode("", $file));
```

**Documentação**

- Função [`file`](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.file.php);
- Função [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-match.php);
- Função [`trim`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.trim.php);
- Função [`unset`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.unset.php);
- Função [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.implode.php);

Comment: Exatamente isso, resolveu meu problema. Obrigado.

Comment: É possível pelo JavaScript via Ajax.

Comment: @DvD apenas se um servidor estiver servidor o arquivo via HTTP, mas mesmo assim não conseguiria salvar novamente o arquivo. Para salvar, teria que ter um *script* rodando no lado do servidor para isso também. Mais prático fazer tudo no PHP mesmo.

Answer (score 0):

### Usando JavaScript com Ajax

O script abaixo irá percorrer linha por linha do arquivo `.txt` excluindo as linhas que não possuírem a string desejada e atualizando o arquivo em tempo real:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Arquivo `filtrar.php`:

```
<?php
$conteudo = $_GET['cont'];
$arquivo = $_GET['arquivo'];
if(isset($conteudo) && isset($arquivo)){
    $fp = fopen($arquivo,"r");
    $texto = fread($fp,filesize($arquivo));
    fclose($fp);

    $fp = fopen($arquivo,"w");
    $nconteudo = str_replace($conteudo, '', $texto);
    $nconteudo = str_replace(str_replace("\n", '', $conteudo), '', $nconteudo);
    fwrite($fp,rtrim($nconteudo));
    fclose($fp);
}else{
?>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<input type="button" value="Iniciar" id="inicio" />
<br /><br />
<div id="processamento">
</div>

<script>

verificar = "55555555555"; // o que quer verificar. Será excluída a linha que não conter isso
meu_arquivo = "arquivo.txt"; // nome do arquivo de origem
tempo_linha = 1; // intervalo de processamento de cada linha, em segundos

var arq = new XMLHttpRequest();
conteudo_idx = 0;
contador = 1;
div_processa = document.getElementById("processamento"); // div com resultados
function lerTexto(arquivo){
    arq.open("GET", arquivo, false);
    arq.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(arq.readyState == 4){
            conteudo = arq.responseText.split("\n");
            div_processa.innerHTML = "Processando "+conteudo.length+" linhas:<br />";
            processa();
        }
    }
    arq.send(null);
}

function processa(){
    if(conteudo_idx < conteudo.length){
        if(conteudo[conteudo_idx].match(verificar)){
            div_processa.innerHTML = div_processa.innerHTML+"&bull; Linha "+contador+": Passou!<br />";
            setTimeout("processa()",tempo_linha*1000);
        }else{
            div_processa.innerHTML = div_processa.innerHTML+"&bull; Linha "+contador+": Não passou!<br />";
            arq.open("GET", "filtrar.php?cont="+encodeURIComponent(conteudo[conteudo_idx]+'\n')+"&arquivo="+meu_arquivo, false);
            arq.onreadystatechange = function(){
                if(arq.readyState == 4){
                    setTimeout("processa()",tempo_linha*1000);
                }
            }
            arq.send(null);
        }
        conteudo_idx++;
        window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
    }else{
        div_processa.innerHTML = '<strong>Processo finalizado!</strong><br />'
        +'<strong style="color: green;">Arquivo <a href="'+meu_arquivo+'" target="_blank">'+meu_arquivo+'</a> gravado!</strong><br />'
        +div_processa.innerHTML;
        scroll(0,0);
    }
    contador++;
}

document.getElementById("inicio").addEventListener('click', function(){
    lerTexto(meu_arquivo+"?"+Math.random());
    this.outerHTML = '';
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
<?php
}
?>
```

> Necessário que os arquivos estejam no mesmo diretório e que o mesmo possua autorização para leitura e escrita.

Comment: Como comentei, uma solução com complexidade bem desnecessária, pois necessitará de um servidor web servindo o arquivo de texto e necessitará de um *script* PHP no servidor para gravar os novos dados. É válido postar a resposta a título de curiosidade, mas ao meu ver, seria um péssimo jeito de resolver o problema. A única situação que eu vejo isso sendo plausível é quando a validação já estivesse implementada em JS e tivesse uma complexidade tão grande que inviabilizaria sua implementação em PHP - o que é extremamente raro acontecer.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Sua resposta não necessita de servidor pra rodar?

Comment: Não, apenas o PHP (interpretador) instalado.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Blz. Não considero "_bem desnecessária_" a solução que propus, é apenas uma forma bem diferente da sua.